# Container failed to start error when running RStudio server with ShinyProxy

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose, rstudio-server, shinyproxy

I'm trying to run RStudio server using ShinyProxy. I can run a container without ShinyProxy fine like this:

```bash
docker run -p 80:8787 -e DISABLE_AUTH=true rocker/rstudio
```

when I navigate to localhost, I can see RStudio server in my browers.

Now, trying to add RStudio server as an application run with Shinyproxy, here is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  shinyproxy:
    container_name: shinyproxy
    image: openanalytics/shinyproxy:latest
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - "./application.yml:/opt/shinyproxy/application.yml:z"
    networks: 
      - sp-example-net
    ports:
      - 80:8080
networks: 
  sp-example-net:
    name: "sp-example-net"
```

and here is my application.yml:

```yaml
proxy:
  port: 8080
  authentication: none
  docker:
      internal-networking: true
  specs:
  - id: rstudio
    container-image: rocker/rstudio
    container-network: sp-example-net
```

If I run this using `docker compose up`, I can navigate to localhost and click on the rstudio link to open rstudio server. But then after maybe 5 seconds I get an error that the container failed to start:

```bash
Error
Status code: 500

Message: Container failed to start

Stack Trace:
eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.ContainerProxyException: Container failed to start
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.startProxy(ProxyService.java:283)
at eu.openanalytics.shinyproxy.controllers.AppController.getOrStart(AppController.java:150)
at eu.openanalytics.shinyproxy.controllers.AppController.startApp(AppController.java:91)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.util.AppRecoveryFilter.doFilter(AppRecoveryFilter.java:63)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.util.AppRecoveryFilter.doFilter(AppRecoveryFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:104)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.util.ProxyMappingManager$ProxyPathHandler.handleRequest(ProxyMappingManager.java:160)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.SameSiteCookieHandler.handleRequest(SameSiteCookieHandler.java:97)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate(DefaultDockerClient.java:2848)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2723)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.createContainer(DefaultDockerClient.java:742)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.createContainer(DefaultDockerClient.java:724)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.docker.DockerEngineBackend.startContainer(DockerEngineBackend.java:99)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.AbstractContainerBackend.doStartProxy(AbstractContainerBackend.java:163)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.AbstractContainerBackend.startProxy(AbstractContainerBackend.java:129)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.startProxy(ProxyService.java:279)
... 112 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2721)
... 118 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:531)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:538)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$null$6(ClientRuntime.java:182)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:288)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$createRunnableForAsyncProcessing$7(ClientRuntime.java:156)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.doConnect(UnixSocketChannel.java:127)
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.connect(UnixSocketChannel.java:136)
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.connect(UnixSocketChannel.java:223)
at com.spotify.docker.client.UnixConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(UnixConnectionSocketFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:483)
```

I'm running this on a Mac with M1 Pro.

The [documentation](https://www.shinyproxy.io/faq/#failed-to-start-container) suggests this could be caused by the firewall blocking ShinyProxy from connecting to the docker API:

> When the docker service is up and running, the most common cause is that the firewall rules on the machine prevent ShinyProxy to connect to the docker API. In that case, it is worthwhile to disable the firewall temporarily and to check whether ShinyProxy is then able to start a container.

It suggests turning off the firewall, but I'm not able to turn the firewall completely off on my Mac.

Comment: Shinyproxy provides a shinyproxy rstudio image that may work better for you [see here](https://hub.docker.com/r/openanalytics/shinyproxy-rstudio-ide-demo/tags). As of now the image is about a year old (not the latest 2022.12 rstudio image).

Comment: See [this demo repository](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-rstudio-ide-demo/) on Github which is maintained by the developers of ShinyProxy and kept up to date with evolving versions of RStudio and ShinyProxy.